# Why can't my non admin users use mlocate command?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, locate

I have a node.js software agent running on 14.04 not able to run many of his bash scripts on a new server. The problem I seem to have is the limited user returns nothing from the locate or mlocate command.

I need to figure out why this command works under my admin user but not under the agent's username.

```
admin@host ~ $ locate 6831-7
/home/example/6831-7.txt
/home/example/6831-7.pdf
/home/example/6831-7.psd

admin@host ~ $ sudo login limited
Password:
limited@host ~ $ locate 6831-7

#it returns nothing
```

Nothing is returned to stdout, which is the problem I have with my scripts. What would cause this program to not return under this limited user?

Comment: locate uses a database to retrieve data. I would assume your non-admin does not get permission to access the database made by the admin. How about you build the database 1st before doing the 2nd locate. I would assume that would make a database with permissions for your normal user. Wild guess though ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I had done a `chmod o+r` on the existing database and he had no problem. Did that and came back here to see your comment.

Comment: O.o Did your `locate` command lose its setgid bit? What is the output of `stat /usr/bin/mlocate`?

Comment: File: ‘/usr/bin/mlocate’
  Size: 39520      Blocks: 80         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 6554518     Links: 1
Access: (2755/-rwxr-sr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  112/ mlocate)
Access: 2016-01-19 07:51:29.532763728 -0500
Modify: 2013-06-20 11:27:40.000000000 -0400
Change: 2015-12-30 16:34:40.133996411 -0500
 Birth: -

Comment: @Rinzwind Rebuilding the database doesn't help nor does reinstalling `mlocate` package. There is a bug report on this issue but in my case I borked my system with a programming bug.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I added the user to the group, only this seemed to do the trick. I edited the permissions for the database with the following command:

```
sudo chmod o+r /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

Provided that the database is located in /var/lib, this adds world read permissions to the database. The limited user was instantly able to return locate to stdout like normal.

Edit: The problem with this solution is that updatedb returns the world permissions to 0. So this is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, when a non-root user runs `locate`, contents of directories the non-root user does not have read access to are not displayed.

In your case, what are the permissions on `/home/example`? If user `limited` does not have read access on `/home/example`, `locate` will not show matching files in that directory when run by `limited`. Assuming there aren't any other files on your system with 6831-7 in the name, your empty results would be expected.

You can test this by seeing if `limited` can use `locate` to find other files on your system that are world readable, for example `/etc/timezone`:

```
limited@host$ locate timezone
/etc/timezone
/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/clock-timezone.page
...
```

If you get results, you know `locate` is able to read the database successfully.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug report on this problem:

- [Unable to use 'locate' to locate files mlocate.db permission denied](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlocate/+bug/281471)

I didn't follow any of the suggestions there because I know how I had broken my system by using `chown` to $USER on `/` instead of `/tmp/$USER/` recursively. It took a day to rebuild my system to boot. `locate` command is one of the left over things to fix.

Because my system is over-powered and under-utilized, I already have `sudo updatedb` running every 15 minutes via `cron`. So I just modified it to reset permissions.

Before change:

```
$ sudo ll /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db

-rw-r----- 1 root mlocate 110953861 Jun 29 20:02 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

Here's tail end of changes to `crontab -e` and what permissions look like:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0   0   1   *   *     /bin/journalctl --vacuum-size=200M
*/15 *  *   *   *     nice updatedb && chmod o+r /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
0  20   *   *   *     /sbin/fstrim /

$ while : ; do ll /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db ; sleep 5m ; done

-rw-r----- 1 root mlocate 110953861 Jun 29 20:02 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r----- 1 root mlocate 110953861 Jun 29 20:02 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mlocate 110954083 Jun 29 20:15 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mlocate 110954083 Jun 29 20:15 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mlocate 110954083 Jun 29 20:15 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mlocate 110959759 Jun 29 20:30 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mlocate 110959759 Jun 29 20:30 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

This is just a band-aid until the root cause (pun noted) is found.